# Converting boost streambuf to string_ref

Tags: boost-asio

The following code compiles fine for me, but given the somewhat complex design of ASIO buffers, I'm not certain it's correct. The intention is to allow the contents of the `streambuf` to be given to an HTTP parser without creating an intermediate `std::string` object, which is what other ASIO code examples seem to do.

```
boost::string_ref makeStringRef(const boost::asio::streambuf& streambuf)
{
    auto&& bufferType = streambuf.data();

    return {
        boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(bufferType),
        boost::asio::buffer_size(bufferType)
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is, indeed, not correct, because the streambuf may have several non-contiguous regions.

So you need to copy anyways. Alternatively, just read into a fixed buffer instead. Of course, this requires you to know the maximum size ahead of time, or read in several steps.

> *By the way, by taking a `const&` you risk creating a `string_ref` that refers to a temporary. Always try to be explicit about life time expectations.*

Comment: Sigh, I feared as much

Comment: String_ref is nice, but it's not a panacea. You need a contiguous source whose lifetime extends beyond that of the reference. In that sense, `string_ref` is nothing different from a regular reference. Only use it when you can. Thinking ahead you can often cause designs that allow lots of "zero-copy" string referencing, but not without that fore-thought, IME.